# Failed to query HTTP URL via AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, cross-domain

I'm getting the error mentioned in the headline when i try query HTTP URL via AJAX from another domain, I always get **error callback**.

> DOMException: Failed to execute 'send' on 'XMLHttpRequest': Failed to load {URL}.

But I can get the URL [**"HERE"**](http://113.196.140.146/v2.3/session?vendor_id=III-DM&token=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&timestamp=1517210918&signature=VpYOWBp0EwEMkuBcJ8Un7Y7dx08=) via browser.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://113.196.140.146/v2.3/session?vendor_id=III-DM&token=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&timestamp=1517210918&signature=VpYOWBp0EwEMkuBcJ8Un7Y7dx08=",
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "json",
    crossDomain: true,
    async: false,
    success: function(resp, status, xhr) {
        console.log(resp);
    },
    error: function(xhr, status, error){
        console.log(error);
    }
});
```

How do I get **success callback** via AJAX?

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: DOMException: Failed to execute 'send' on 'XMLHttpRequest': Failed to load. I've updated it.

Comment: do you request ajax from 113.196.140.146 or another domain?

Comment: @ewwink I request ajax from another domain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The remote server returns the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header twice and the ajax process has been failed.

According to official CORS [documentation](https://www.w3.org/TR/cors/)

> If the response includes zero or more than one
>   Access-Control-Allow-Origin header values, return fail and terminate
>   this algorithm.

The article describes the error which you encountered. I have attached the image about response headers which is returned from server (`113.196.140.146`). You can see the duplicate headers of `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`.

[image]